# FullCalendar event removal

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am currently using the Full Calendar JQuery plugin on my webpage. I am having one small problem with it. On eventClick, a dialog is opened asking the user to name their event. That is fine.

However, when the user escapes this UI, I wish for the event to be removed from the fullCalendar view completely. By default, a blue box is left there. showing where the event would have been placed. If you click anywhere that isn't on the fullCalendar screen, then it will escape this blue box.

I have an alert being displayed when the user exits the dialog that prompts them for an event name, all I need to figure out is the code to remove the blue box that is generated!

The function `revertFunc();` will not seem to do this, I assume because the event has not actually been created.

Does anyone know what could be used in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a removeEvents method

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/removeEvents/